# Correcting bad band saw cuts on an aluminum bar

Tags: metal, cutting, metal-cutting

I am trying to make a rigid aluminum box with a top for use in a 20 ton arbor press (I do not plan to subject the box to 20 tons but it may see 4-5) to press glass fret in. I salvaged some 3/8 inch thick plate that students used to learn how to use a drill press so it is full of holes. I was able to salvage some workable rectangular prism strips to make the sides of my box, but the band saw was not cutting straight so my cuts are not square. I wanna clean up the edges i cut with an end mill. My problem is the cuts are pretty bad so I am not sure how i can preset a surface will be square after I level it with the end mill.

Anyone have any good ideas for this? Doesn't have to be perfect but needs to be decent for my weld step.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've used miter saws for just such work. A carbide-tipped blade will do the job. Cut slowly.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your situation. Is the bar straight/flat? If so isherwood's suggestion is best. If the bar isn't perfectly straight/flat, then you need to clamp or otherwise attach it to a known flat reference face, and then flatten the side opposite to the reference face.

Comment: With a mill this wont be hard. Lock the plate into the vice close to square. cut it off, then flip the plate over supporting on the fresh cut and cut the next surface. Now you have 2 parallel surfaces. If your vice is large enough (and square on the table) Clamp the 2 cut edges in the vice and cut one end then the other it should be square now. If your vice is not long enough clamp to the table and use the table as the square.